# how can i stream video and audio file on website

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, html5-audio, audio-streaming, video.js

I am using video.js and audio.js for showing audio and video files on website,i don't want to convert video and audio files to different formats and bitrates.I want to know how can i stream videos and audio files which are uploaded by users.I am not talking about live streaming.
Ask for extra information if you want.
Give me some good learning resources and steps for doing this.please.
thanks !!

Comment: To support different browsers, you need to convert video and audio to different formats OR you decide not to support all browsers.

Comment: what is your understanding of live streaming ? HLS or HTTP live streaming is an industry standard way to stream media from server across internet to clients (mobile/browsers) - when client is consuming the media (watching/listening), as opposed to just downloading for later consumption, it minimizes bandwidth usage since the client is only sent as its being consumed, in a series of 6 second clips - if this does not match your use case then please expound - if it does match let us know and we will offer more detailed advice - PS. you might also look at websockets

Comment: my site allowing users to upload specific formats and if browser doesn't understand format then it fallback to flash @MikkoOhtamaa

Comment: yes,i am talking about http live streaming,when user listening and watching,the video and audio is sent to user in 6 second clip. i want answer related to video.js and audio.js.I want to know, is it really important to convert video and audio to different format,because video.js and audio.js can play many format in different browser with flash fallback.please give some good advice.

Comment: i am want to explain one more time,in my website user is uploading audio and video file to server,then i am using audio.js and video.js for displaying video and audio files to users,i am not talking about live streaming like from webcam.

Answer (score 1):

> i don't want to convert video and audio files to different formats and bitrates

If that is your requirement, you should not do this project.

Streaming media to many different browsers and devices requires transcoding the original media into a few different codecs and formats.  There are services you can utilize that do most of the work for you, but it's anything but a cakewalk and will require significant effort on your part to integrate.

Comment: Is it really important to convert video and audio to different format,because if browser doesn't understand format then video.js and audio.js fallback to flash.

Comment: i don't want to convert videos and audios to different format but i want to transcode media to suitable codec so that it can stream easily.i only allow user to upload mp3 for audio and mp4,webm,ogv,3gpp

Comment: i do some research and found that html5 support mp4 with h.264 (video codec) and AAC or mp3 (audio codec),and webm with vp8(video codec) and Vorbis(audio codec).i want to know,is all mp4 and webm videos comes with these codecs or i need to encode videos.